# Bad SEO ranking because of masterpage internal redirect in Umbraco

Tags: seo, umbraco

I've seen questions similar to this but there is no solid answer to them, so I asked again. I have an Umbraco website. Root document of the website uses a master page template with a placeholder that any page renders within it.
I've used the `umbracoInternalRedirectId` field to internally redirects the master page to the homepage.

This method works fine for the website but I think it is a bad idea due to **SEO** rules because in "**Fetch as Google**" of Google webmaster, I can see "**Redirection**" alert and in detail, it shows me that the document moved permanently.

Is there any solution apart from changing the structure?

Edited:
My structure:

- Root

  - Home
  - About us
  - Contact Us
  - etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can build up your Umbraco website with the root node being the actual frontpage. That means you won't need to do any redirects using umbracoInternalRedirectId.

The ContentFinder in Umbraco will by default show the first root node.
This is how I usually build my Umbraco sites:

- -- ROOT --
- Homepage

  - About us
  - Gallery
  - Etc.
- Other language "homepage"

Does that make sense?

Comment: Your solution is right, but in that way, I must change the structure of the website (I will do that next time). I have kinds of inheritances among my document types. In the root node, I have lots of special configuration for the website. In addition, there are some shared attributes like metadata too. If you work with CMS like Kentico, there is a document type named "Page (menu item)" that could be used for any page (especially pages not like the news, or ...). I've created "Page" document type too, so my "Homepage" uses Page document type with a special Home template. Is there any other way?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no other way to achieve this, without doing a redirect like you're already doing. I would suggest you take your configuration from your root node and place it in a "Settings"-node and solve your issue that way. Then you'd be able to have your homepage as your root node.

Comment: Thank you @Mikkel